# Trouble finding understanding why complexity of two nested loops is O(n)?

Tags: java, time-complexity

So in the following code, `j` executes `n` times when `i = 0`. As soon as i iterates once `(i = 0,2,3....n)`, `j` never executes, as the condition of the if statement is true and `n` is added to `j`. `i` continues to iterate until `n` which is when the loop (both loops) stop execution and the method ends.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if(j < i) j = j + n;
                else x = x+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

My confusion lies in why the time complexity is `O(n)` when both loops iterate to `n` at some point, `i` always iterates to `n` and `j` iterates to `n` when `i = 0`... Should it not be `O(n^2)` as we are multiplying `nxn`?

Comment: Why do you know it is O(n)?

Comment: "My confusion lies in why the time complexity is `O(n)`" - Why do you think it's `O(n)`? The inner for loop is equivalent to `for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)`

Comment: Sorry guys my bad, i did an edit

Comment: 'if (j < i)' instead of 'if (j > i)'

Answer (score 5):

The innermost condition, `if (j < i)`, is always true when `i >= 1`, as `j` is initialized to `0`.  Because you increment `j` by `n` inside the if-statement, this is equivalent to calling `break;`, thus exiting the innermost for-loop after a single iteration.

So to answer your question, the time complexity is `O(n)` because the innermost for-loop will only iterate `2n - 1` times:

- It iterates to `n` when `i == 0`.
- When `i > 0`, it only iterates once.

Thanks for [Phoenix1355](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859546/trouble-finding-understanding-why-complexity-of-two-nested-loops-is-on/55859643#comment98380410_55859643) for pointing this out below in the comments.

Comment: Do you mean the innermost for loop will be execute once per loop of the outermost?

Comment: @CameronDowner Yes, I'll edit the answer to make that more clear. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Good answer, took me a post-it note!

Comment: Wouldn't the time complexity be `O(2n)`? The `x` would result in `n`, but the inner loop would iterate twice the size of `n` since the outer loop would run it `n` times.

Comment: I disagree with this.  A bubble sort will execute at most once per outer loop but it is considered O(n^2).  In fact, the above example and a bubble sort iterate almost the exact same number of times for both outer and inner.

Comment: @jim829 Can you elaborate? [This example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) shows it iterating much more than once per outer loop.

Comment: @JacobG. That will still make it `O(2n)` (`O(2n-1)` exactly). The innermost for-loop would still iterate a total of `2n` times. `n` times the first iteration of the outermost for-loop and then `n-1` times more, even if `i > 0`.

Comment: @Phoenix1355 Makes sense, but constants are dropped regardless, so it's still correct to say that it's `O(n)`.

Comment: Ok.  . You guys are correct (no surprise there).  Sorry for wasting your time with my earlier insanity.

Comment: @Phoenix1355 Is there any way you can elaborate that in an answer. This happens to be a homework question and you are 100% correct. I would be very grateful

Comment: Going back to your answer @JacobG. in 2n-1, is the n coming from the iterations of 'i' which go to 'n' regardless? And since j only iterates once, is that a constant in this case?

Comment: @CosmicCat When `i` is `0`, `j` iterates `n` times. When `i > 0`, `j` iterates once. `2n - 1` is just the amount of times that the innermost for-loop iterates.

Comment: So really since both loops are dependant on each other we just get O(n) instead of O(n^2)?

Answer (score 1):

You can also analyze the time complexity by passing different inputs (n). I copied the same code and created a separate function:

```
private static void testComplexity(int n) {
    int x = 0;
    int N1 = 0, N2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            N1++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                N2++;
            if(j < i) j = j + n;
            else x = x+1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("input is : " + n + " and N1 " + N1 + " and N2 : " + N2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] inputs = new int[]{10, 100, 1000, 10000};
    for(int input : inputs) testComplexity(input);
}
```

The output is:

> input is : 10 and N1 : 10 and N2 : 19 
>   input is : 100 and N1 : 100 and N2 : 199 
>   input is : 1000 and N1 : 1000 and N2 : 1999 
>   input is : 10000 and N1 : 10000 and N2 : 19999

I created another function for **QUADRATIC**

```
    private static void testComplexity2(int n) {
    int N1 = 0, N2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            N1++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                N2++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("input is : " + n + " and N1 " + N1 + " and N2 : " + N2);
}
```

The output is :

> input is : 10 and N1 10 and N2 : 100 
>   input is : 100 and N1 100 and N2 : 10000
>   input is : 1000 and N1 1000 and N2 : 1000000
>   input is : 10000 and N1 10000 and N2 : 100000000

**Do you see difference ?**